How can i add a delete button to delete files uploaded to localstorage?
how can i add a delete button to apear when i select an uploaded photo?
I tried a multiple things but didn.t work.
I.m new and i try to do my best
To be clear with what the result i want to get :
I created a upload button that instant show uploaded images to the page.
Now i want to add a delete button that apears on images when they go full-screen, and by pressing the delete button, to delete the image.
This is the code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Încarcă și afișează imagini</title>

<style>
    h1 {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    #image-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap; /* Nu permite ca imaginile să se mute pe linie nouă */
        overflow-x: auto; /* Scrollează orizontal dacă depășește lățimea containerului */
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .uploaded-image {
        margin-right: 10px;
        cursor: pointer; /* Adăugăm un cursor de tip pointer pentru a indica că imaginea este clicabilă */
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>salut</h1>

<input type="file" id="file-input" multiple>
<div id="image-container"></div>

<script>
document.getElementById('file-input').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var files = this.files;
    if (files) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function(file) {
                return function(e) {
                    var image = new Image();
                    image.src = e.target.result;
                    image.className = 'uploaded-image'; // Adăugăm clasa 'uploaded-image' pentru a aplica stilurile CSS
                    image.onload = function() {
                        var imageContainer = document.getElementById('image-container');
                        imageContainer.appendChild(image);
                        
                        // Salvăm imaginea în localStorage
                        var imageDataURL = e.target.result;
                        var images = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('images')) || [];
                        images.push(imageDataURL);
                        localStorage.setItem('images', JSON.stringify(images));
                    };

                    // Adăugăm evenimentul de click pentru a afișa imaginea în full screen
                    image.addEventListener('click', function() {
                        showFullScreenImage(image.src);
                    });
                };
            })(files[i]);
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
        }
    }
});

// Funcție pentru a afișa imaginile stocate în localStorage
function displayStoredImages() {
    var images = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('images')) || [];
    var imageContainer = document.getElementById('image-container');
    images.forEach(function(imageDataURL) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = imageDataURL;
        image.className = 'uploaded-image';
        imageContainer.appendChild(image);

        // Adăugăm evenimentul de click pentru a afișa imaginea în full screen
        image.addEventListener('click', function() {
            showFullScreenImage(image.src);
        });
    });
}

// Funcție pentru afișarea imaginii în full screen
function showFullScreenImage(imageSrc) {
    var fullScreenContainer = document.createElement('div');
    fullScreenContainer.style.position = 'fixed';
    fullScreenContainer.style.top = '0';
    fullScreenContainer.style.left = '0';
    fullScreenContainer.style.width = '100%';
    fullScreenContainer.style.height = '100%';
    fullScreenContainer.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)';
    fullScreenContainer.style.display = 'flex';
    fullScreenContainer.style.alignItems = 'center';
    fullScreenContainer.style.justifyContent = 'center';
    fullScreenContainer.style.zIndex = '9999';

    var fullScreenImageContainer = document.createElement('div');
    fullScreenImageContainer.style.position = 'relative'; // Permite poziționarea butonului de ștergere
    fullScreenImageContainer.style.maxWidth = '100%';
    fullScreenImageContainer.style.maxHeight = '100%';

    var fullScreenImage = new Image();
    fullScreenImage.src = imageSrc;
    fullScreenImage.style.width = '100%';
    fullScreenImage.style.height = 'auto';

    var deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    deleteButton.innerText = 'Șterge'; // Textul butonului de ștergere
    deleteButton.style.position = 'absolute'; // Poziționează butonul de ștergere în colțul din dreapta sus
    deleteButton.style.top = '5px';
    deleteButton.style.right = '5px';
    deleteButton.style.padding = '5px';
    deleteButton.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    deleteButton.style.color = 'white';
    deleteButton.style.border = 'none';
    deleteButton.style.cursor = 'pointer';

    // Adăugăm evenimentul de click pentru a șterge imaginea când butonul este apăsat
    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Ștergem imaginea din container
        fullScreenContainer.parentNode.removeChild(fullScreenContainer);
        // Ștergem imaginea din localStorage
        var images = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('images')) || [];
        var index = images.indexOf(imageSrc);
        if (index !== -1) {
            images.splice(index, 1);
            localStorage.setItem('images', JSON.stringify(images));
        }
    });

    fullScreenImageContainer.appendChild(fullScreenImage);
    fullScreenContainer.appendChild(fullScreenImageContainer);
    fullScreenImageContainer.appendChild(deleteButton); // Adăugăm butonul de ștergere la containerul imaginii în ecran complet
    document.body.appendChild(fullScreenContainer);
}


// Funcție pentru afișarea imaginii în full screen
function showFullScreenImage(imageSrc) {
    var fullScreenContainer = document.createElement('div');
    fullScreenContainer.style.position = 'fixed';
    fullScreenContainer.style.top = '0';
    fullScreenContainer.style.left = '0';
    fullScreenContainer.style.width = '100%';
    fullScreenContainer.style.height = '100%';
    fullScreenContainer.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)';
    fullScreenContainer.style.display = 'flex';
    fullScreenContainer.style.alignItems = 'center';
    fullScreenContainer.style.justifyContent = 'center';
    fullScreenContainer.style.zIndex = '9999';

    var fullScreenImage = new Image();
    fullScreenImage.src = imageSrc;
    fullScreenImage.style.maxWidth = '100%';
    fullScreenImage.style.maxHeight = '100%';

    fullScreenImage.addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.body.removeChild(fullScreenContainer);
    });

    fullScreenContainer.appendChild(fullScreenImage);
    document.body.appendChild(fullScreenContainer);
}

// Apelăm funcția pentru a afișa imaginile stocate în localStorage
displayStoredImages();
</script>

</body>
</html>


Thank you!!!
I tried this but didn.t work
    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Ștergem imaginea din container
        fullScreenContainer.parentNode.removeChild(fullScreenContainer);
        // Ștergem imaginea din localStorage
        var images = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('images')) || [];
        var index = images.indexOf(imageSrc);
        if (index !== -1) {
            images.splice(index, 1);
            localStorage.setItem('images', JSON.stringify(images));
        }
    });

    fullScreenImageContainer.appendChild(fullScreenImage);
    fullScreenContainer.appendChild(fullScreenImageContainer);
    fullScreenImageContainer.appendChild(deleteButton); // Adăugăm butonul de ștergere la containerul imaginii în ecran complet
    document.body.appendChild(fullScreenContainer);
}




It works and deletes the image from localStorage, but not from the display.
To fix that we just hide the image which is now the argument for the function showFullScreenImage (instead of its imageSrc) so that we can refer back to the original image.

document.getElementById('file-input').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var files = this.files;
    if (files) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function (file) {
                return function (e) {
                    var image = new Image();
                    image.src = e.target.result;
                    image.className = 'uploaded-image'; // Adăugăm clasa 'uploaded-image' pentru a aplica stilurile CSS
                    image.onload = function () {
                        var imageContainer = document.getElementById('image-container');
                        imageContainer.appendChild(image);

                        // Salvăm imaginea în localStorage
                        var imageDataURL = e.target.result;
                        var images = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('images')) || [];
                        images.push(imageDataURL);
                        localStorage.setItem('images', JSON.stringify(images));
                    };

                    // Adăugăm evenimentul de click pentru a afișa imaginea în full screen
                    image.addEventListener('click', function () {
                        showFullScreenImage(image);
                    });
                };
            })(files[i]);
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
        }
    }
});

// Funcție pentru a afișa imaginile stocate în localStorage
function displayStoredImages() {
    var images = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('images')) || [];
    var imageContainer = document.getElementById('image-container');
    images.forEach(function (imageDataURL) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = imageDataURL;
        image.className = 'uploaded-image';
        imageContainer.appendChild(image);

        // Adăugăm evenimentul de click pentru a afișa imaginea în full screen
        image.addEventListener('click', function () {
            showFullScreenImage(image);
        });
    });
}

// Funcție pentru afișarea imaginii în full screen
function showFullScreenImage(image) {
    imageSrc = image.src
    var fullScreenContainer = document.createElement('div');
    fullScreenContainer.style.position = 'fixed';
    fullScreenContainer.style.top = '0';
    fullScreenContainer.style.left = '0';
    fullScreenContainer.style.width = '100%';
    fullScreenContainer.style.height = '100%';
    fullScreenContainer.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)';
    fullScreenContainer.style.display = 'flex';
    fullScreenContainer.style.alignItems = 'center';
    fullScreenContainer.style.justifyContent = 'center';

    var fullScreenImageContainer = document.createElement('div');
    fullScreenImageContainer.style.position = 'relative'; // Permite poziționarea butonului de ștergere
    fullScreenImageContainer.style.maxWidth = '100%';
    fullScreenImageContainer.style.maxHeight = '100%';

    var fullScreenImage = new Image();
    fullScreenImage.src = imageSrc;
    fullScreenImage.style.width = '100%';
    fullScreenImage.style.height = 'auto';

    var deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    deleteButton.innerText = 'Șterge'; // Textul butonului de ștergere
    deleteButton.style.position = 'absolute'; // Poziționează butonul de ștergere în colțul din dreapta sus
    deleteButton.style.top = '5px';
    deleteButton.style.right = '5px';
    deleteButton.style.padding = '5px';
    deleteButton.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    deleteButton.style.color = 'white';
    deleteButton.style.border = 'none';
    deleteButton.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    deleteButton.style.zIndex = '111';

    // Adăugăm evenimentul de click pentru a șterge imaginea când butonul este apăsat
    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Ștergem imaginea din container
        fullScreenContainer.parentElement.removeChild(fullScreenContainer);
        // Ștergem imaginea din localStorage
        var images = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('images')) || [];
        var index = images.indexOf(imageSrc);
        if (index !== -1) {
            images.splice(index, 1);
            localStorage.setItem('images', JSON.stringify(images));
        }

        image.style.display = 'none'
    });

    fullScreenImageContainer.appendChild(fullScreenImage);
    fullScreenContainer.appendChild(fullScreenImageContainer);
    fullScreenImageContainer.appendChild(deleteButton); // Adăugăm butonul de ștergere la containerul imaginii în ecran complet
    document.body.appendChild(fullScreenContainer);
}

// Apelăm funcția pentru a afișa imaginile stocate în localStorage
displayStoredImages();

